# Correctly mounting windows partition

Tags: permissions, mount, windows, fstab

i have set up a multiboot with Linux Mint 17.3 64-Bit on 256GB SSD and Windows 7 64-Bit on a 3TB HD. I have symbolic links from Linux to the Windows Partition, so my Pictures, Documents, Downloads, Videos and SteamAppData (for Steam in Wine) are stored on my 3TB HDD on the Windows Partition. The Problem is now, that i have User Rights issues on Windows, means, that i need Admin rights to access any folders and files created from Linux. I think i have a "misconfigured" fstab file, which doesn’t sets the permissions correct.

Here the actual line:

```
UUID=!theUUID! /media/windows ntfs-3g auto,user,suid,permissions,locale=de_AT.UTF-8,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names,exec 0 0
```

Or do I have to do some chown and chmod when shutting down Linux?

Thanks

Comment: what's your user id ? because it's 1000 in your mount option umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000

Comment: dont use chown on your ntfs partition

Comment: my linux user id and group is 1000.

maybe the umask is wrong?

Comment: no 22 is ccorrect try just fstab UUID=!theUUID! /media/windows ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000    0       0

Answer (score -2):

You could use file manager in this way:

1. Go to windows parent directory that contains files you need to link.
2. Left click on this directory to mark it.
3. Right click on it and by the menu create the link of the directory.
4. Cut and paste the link in your /home.

The link should work now double-clicking it.

Comment: And why? I already have my Symlinks sucsessfully created. Its just about, that linux doesnt set the rights correctly for windows.

Comment: I didn't understand if my little procedure worked for you or not.